# Why can't I return brothers types with common ancestor in a conditional operator?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, type-conversion, conditional-operator

Why can't I return brothers types with common ancestor in a conditional operator?

Why doesn't C# support this?

```
class Polygon
{
    public int CountSides { get; set; }
}

class Rectangle : Polygon { }

class Circle : Polygon { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Polygon p = true ? new Circle() : new Rectangle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation for the ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
>
> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

The two data types (`Circle` and `Rectangle`) are not the same. There also is no [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) between them. So therefore it is not legal.

If you cast both as `Polygon`, then it passes the first condition. If you cast just one of them as 'Polygon', it passes the second condition.

Answer (score 3):

It does, you just need to cast:

```
class Polygon
{
    public int CountSides { get; set; }
}

class Rectangle : Polygon { }

class Circle : Polygon { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Polygon p = true ? (Polygon)new Circle() : (Polygon)new Rectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: just to add - `Polygon p = true ? (Polygon)new Circle() : new Rectangle();` is enough. (The type is inferred from the `true` path)